# How preload self-hosted fonts with Next.js? Console warning "The resource was not used within a few seconds."

Tags: html, css, fonts, next.js, preload

In my Next.js project I would like to preload my self-hosted fonts.

My _app.js contains:

```
<Head>
        <link
          rel="preload"
          href="/fonts/leira/Leira-Lite.ttf"
          as="font"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
          type="font/ttf"
        />
</Head>
```

My globals.scss contains:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Leira";
  src: url("/fonts/leira/Leira-Lite.ttf");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

But this doesn't work. The console (on Firefox) logs **"The resource at “url/fonts/leira/Leira-Lite.ttf” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly."**.
The problem seems to be that the font file gets hashed, but I haven't found a solution to this so far.

Comment: [this might help](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/6517)

Answer (score 2):

I now found out that I got the console warnings because I used relative paths to my public folder instead of absolute paths. This produced hashed font files in the .next folder. With the absolute paths the console warnings are gone and the fonts preload, so the issue is solved now. The code above works.